# SCV import : Special characters not supported

Tags: html, facebook, excel, csv, utf-8

I imported CSV file to Sendible.com (Facebook publication scheduler) folowing those instructions : http://blog.sendible.com/tag/csv/

Problem : When I write a "Message" that contain special caracters, result looks wrong. (CSV model : Message,Subject,SendDate)

"message" exemple :

```
Règle n°1 : Respecter les lois.
```

Result on the website sheduler prevew and on facebook when it was published :

```
Rï¿½gle nï¿½1 : Respecter les lois.
```

So I tried to use HTML like this :

```
R&#232;gle n&#176;1 : Respecter les lois.
```

Result looks right on the website sheduler prevew :

```
Règle n°1 : Respecter les lois.
```

but when it was published on facebook, it looks wrong :

```
R&#232;gle n&#176;1 : Respecter les lois.
```

So if you have something that could help me, let me know. Thank you beforehand

Comment: That's a bug in sendible.  Well, 2 bugs actually - It shouldn't be letting you drop raw html into the preview and it should accept UTF-8 which apparently it isn't (you can confirm your file is ok by opening your csv in notepad.)

Either way it's out of your hands.

Comment: Ok thx, so I can not do anything except to wait ?

Answer (score 0):

`ï¿½` indicate the [unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character#Replacement_character), encoded in utf-8 (`0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`) and interpreted in cp1252 (`ï¿½`). In most cases it indicates that something was decoded in an UTF encoding, where that something was encoded in some other encoding.

The least you could do is to save the file as UTF-8 and then upload again:

- Open the original file, see that you see what you expect
- Select save as
- In the save as dialog, look for the tools dropdown menu left to the save button; select Web options
- In the web options dialog, select Encoding tab
- In the encoding tab, select Unicode (UTF-8) from the dropdown menu
- Save the file as CSV
- Upload the new file

Edit: It seems this doesn't actually work, seeing the resulting file in a hex editor and it still is cp1252...

But since csv is a plain text format, you can open it in a normal text editor like notepad, and then save as, and select UTF-8 from the encoding menu.

Comment: Thx, I tried encoding UTF8 using notepad but it did not work.
I got this on facebook Hï¿½llo (original was "Héllo")